# Inject value at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have repository classes that require runtime values taken from `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` (i.e. authorization claims) in combination with regular singleton classes.

Given

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly DependencyClass _dependency;
    private readonly string claim;

    protected MyRepository(DependencyClass _dependency, string claim)
    {
        //...
```

When registering the repository, how can the claim be injected? e.g.

```
unity.RegisterType<IMyRepository, MyRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
unity.RegisterType<DependencyClass>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

`InjectionConstructor` seems to match the constructor parameters and therefore causes a runtime error. Still I'd prefer constructor injection, I'm just not sure how do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have repository classes that require runtime values

Your DI container should build up object graph that contain injectables/components; the classes that contain your application's logic. Runtime data should not be injected into a component's constructor, because that will complicate constructing, building and verifying the object graphs.

Instead, runtime data should be passed through the object graph using method calls. A general solution for this kind of contextual runtime data is to have an abstraction that provides this contextual data to its consumers.

In your case for instance, an `IClaimsContext` abstraction does the trick:

```
public interface IClaimsContext {
    string CurrentClaim { get; }
}
```

Using this abstraction, it is trivial to create an implementation that reads the claims from the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as you can see here:

```
public sealed class ThreadClaimsContext : IClaimsContext {
    public string CurrentClaim {
        get { return Thread.CurrentPrincipal... /* get claims here */; }
    }
}
```

Since this implementation contains no state, it can be registered as singleton without any problem:

```
unity.RegisterInstance<IClaimsContext>(new ThreadClaimsContext());
```

Now your `MyRepository` can simply depend on `IClaimsContext` instead of a `string claims`.